# Variable has been assigned, but the value is null

Tags: c#, function, debugging, variables, unity-game-engine

[Picture of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPcP2.jpg)  After I went from the menu scene to game scene.

[Picture of Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkw3V.png)

I am trying to load the position of the player upon transitioning from the menu to the game scene, but I am getting an error saying that my variable, player is null. I have printed the value of my variable, player in the start and update functions and they both say that player has a value, but when I tried to access it in my loadPosition function  from the Game scene, it gives me an error saying that player is null. After hours of pondering, I feel like the reason that the variable player is null, is because I am calling toWorld() from the Menu scene and not the Game scene.Is there any way to call the start function from a different scene before I transition to the Game scene. This error has been driving me nuts! I deleted the irrelevant part of my code for ease of reading. By the way, Demo is my game scene. Thank you in advance!

```
GameObject player;


    void Update(){

    if (Application.loadedLevelName == "Demo") {
    savePosition ();
    print(player);
    }
}

void Start () {
    if (Application.loadedLevelName == "Demo"){
        player = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player");
        print (player);
    }

}

public void loadPosition(){

    float playerX = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("PlayerX");
    float playerY = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("PlayerY");
    float playerZ = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("PlayerZ");
    player.transform.position = new Vector3 (playerX, playerY, playerZ);

}


public void savePosition(){


    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("PlayerX", player.transform.position.x);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("PlayerY", player.transform.position.y);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("PlayerZ", player.transform.position.z);
    float playerX = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("PlayerX");
    float playerY = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("PlayerY");
    float playerZ = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("PlayerZ");
    print (new Vector3 (playerX, playerY, playerZ));
}
```

Comment: I think including a `OnLevelWasLoaded` function for finding the Player should work.

Comment: @GunnarB. I tried using GameObject.FindWithTag("Player") in the OnLevelWasLoaded function, and Unity was still giving me the error. :/

Comment: Make, for debugging, player a public and have a look in the inspector at runtime.

Comment: @GunnarB. The player variable is assigned during runtime. The function just can't access it for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`player` is `null` because of

`player = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player");`

is likely failing. Make sure that your the GameObject's tag is "Player". If the tag is not "Player" then `FindWithTag` will fail. If this keeps happening, rename that GameObject to "`Player`" in the Editor.

then try this:

```
player = GameObject.Find("Player");
```

That should solve the null problem.

EDIT:

Remove `loadPosition()` from `toWorld()` function and put it after `GameObject.Find("Ethan")` in the `OnLevelWasLoaded()` function and before `print(player)`

Comment: My tag is "Player". I guess that player = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player"); is failing.

Comment: The error is still there even after I used GameObject.Find("Player").

Comment: Yes, rename it then use GameObject.Find(). This is the second question with FindWithTag having this problem this month. There is probably a bug with FindWithTag.

Comment: Update your question with a screenshot of your GameObject hierarchy.

Comment: Fro your picture, you did not rename the GameObject to "Player". I don't see any gameobject called player. do that...

Comment: I used GameObject.Find("Ethan") in my script. @Programmer

Comment: I now see that. You assigning Ethan twice. One from Start and One from OnLevelWasLoaded. Comment the OnLevelWasLoaded code for now. Put GameObject.Find("Ethan") outside the if statement.. Also Where are you calling "toWorld()" function from? ..

Comment: From the menu scene. Sorry for the ambiguity in my question. The "it" in my question was unclear. @Programmer

Comment: I don't understand your last statement but I think the problem here is the `toWorld()` function. Try this: Remove `loadPosition()`  from `toWorld()` function and put it after `GameObject.Find("Ethan")` in the `OnLevelWasLoaded()` function and before `print(player)`.

Comment: Yeah, now it works! All I had to do was place the loadPosition function in the onLevelWasLoaded() function. Thank you @Programmer